# Is it possible to use proxy/socks with http2 client in Go?

Tags: http, go, client, http2

I found, implementation of transport in http2 package doesn't support proxy/socks for http2 client. Is there an simple way to make it work?

Comment: Are you certain it doesn't support it? Do you have an http proxy that works with HTTP2? If you're trying to use a socks5 proxy, that has nothing to do with the http protocol itself, so that should work regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I seem to recall something a while ago about the http2 client not working with HTTP/SOCKS5 proxies. Anyway time has moved on and the below works fine (if that's what you're after). Note that if using a custom DialTLS within the Transport, proxied connections still aren't supported.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    var addressString = "https://www.facebook.com/"
    var proxyString = "socks5://127.0.0.1:9150"

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", addressString, nil)
    tr := &http.Transport{
        Proxy: func(req *http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
            proxyURI, err := url.Parse(proxyString)
            return proxyURI, err
        },
    }

   // The http client is equipped to handle http/2 connections
    hc := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
    resp, _ := hc.Do(req)
    log.Print(resp)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to communicate over sockets something like this should work:

```
socket := "<socket-path>"
// server
sock, err := net.Listen("unix", socket)
go http.Serve(s, nil)

//client
httpc := http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        DialContext: func(_ context.Context, _, _ string) (net.Conn, error) {
            return net.Dial("unix", socket)
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: The question is about using a proxy, not unix domain sockets.

Comment: got it, my mistake, I misread the question. A proxy shouldn't be affected by the http2 implementation though.. I wouldn't think.